# Merging PDF with Data batch

Tags: javascript, batch-file, pdf, merge

I'm a new french stackoverflow user, so sorry for my misspelling.

I would like to know how to automatically merge  writable/alterable `PDF` with data file(`XML`, `TXT` or `FDF`).

I have seen that `Adobe Acrobat Pro` could import Data, but in the wizard action, I've not found "import" choice to make it automatic. The wizard offers `JavaScript` add but i don't find any `PDF` manipulation line code JS.

Does `JavaScript` is the solution for my issue ?

Or do you have some alternative ?

Thx for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the COM of Acrobat or PDFCreator to do it. There is a lot of example here (And in French):

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d431662/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/contribuez/excel-word-pdf-adobe-acrobat-pro-pdfcreator/

Answer (score 0):

With "Wizard", you are using the Actions Wizard?

If so, this is understandable. However, there is the Acrobat JavaScript function which would import an FDF (or a few other data formats); have a closer look at the importAnFDF() method in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation (which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website).

There are other approaches, by importing a tab-delimited file as File Attachment (aka Data Object), and then interpret this file to create your data table, and then use Acrobat JavaScript to fill out the form, save or print it, and so on.

A third method would be using Template pages in the PDF, craft your FDF so that it supports Templates, import it into the base document and then wait until it has spawned all the pages. You then have one big document containing all the filled forms.

Finally, if you have a higher volume, you will be better off using a server-side fill-in tool, such as FDFMerge by Appligent.